# sort at jobs chronologically

Tags: date, sort, at

Possibly a simple solution I misplaced. 
How can I get the output of `atq` sorted chronologically, so I can easily see who's due to run next?  The `man` page for `sort` doesn't have anything built-in to recognize timestamps like the following:

```
atq
1264    Sat Mar 24 15:03:00 2012 a master
1445    Sat Mar 24 20:28:00 2012 a master
1548    Sun Mar 25 15:09:00 2012 a master
1193    Sat Mar 24 11:03:00 2012 a master
1359    Sat Mar 24 17:13:00 2012 a master
1726    Mon Mar 26 21:24:00 2012 a master
1736    Mon Mar 26 22:04:00 2012 a master
1748    Mon Mar 26 22:46:00 2012 a master
1704    Mon Mar 26 20:19:00 2012 a master
1288    Sat Mar 24 15:38:00 2012 a master
1532    Sun Mar 25 11:53:00 2012 a master
```

`atq |sort` wouldn't work either at the job id's jump around.

Comment: I'm okay with reformatting the 2nd field as  2012-03-23_13-11-01 which is sorting-friendly, which I think `date` can do. With the `--date=STRING` param and  `+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux, the output of `atq` always has the date in the same format. Sort the fields in the appropriate order, taking care to declare which ones are numbers or month names. Make sure to use an English locale for the month names since that's what `atq` uses.

```
atq | sort -k 6n -k 3M -k 4n -k 5 -k 7 -k 1
#          year  month day   time queue id
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sort` command can do it, but unfortunately, you can't use `--month-sort` and `--numeric-sort` together.  So use:

```
$ atq |
    sed 's/Jan/1/;s/Feb/2/;s/Mar/3/;s/Apr/4/;s/May/5/;s/Jun/6/;s/Jul/7/;s/Aug/8/;s/Sep/9/;s/Oct/10/;s/Nov/11/;s/Dec/12/' |
    sort -n -k6,6 -k3,4
```

This will convert the month abbreviations to their numeric values, then sort first on year (`-k6,6`), then month and day (`-k3,4`).  The output won't have the month names, but if you really wanted, you could convert those back with another `sed`.

```
$ atq |
    sed 's/Jan/1/;s/Feb/2/;s/Mar/3/;s/Apr/4/;s/May/5/;s/Jun/6/;s/Jul/7/;s/Aug/8/;s/Sep/9/;s/Oct/10/;s/Nov/11/;s/Dec/12/' |
    sort -n -k6,6 -k3,4 |
    sed 'h;s/^[0-9][0-9]*  *[A-Z][a-z][a-z] *\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/;s/10/Oct/;s/11/Nov/;s/12/Dec/;s/1/Jan/;s/2/Feb/;s/3/Mar/;s/4/Apr/;s/5/May/;s/6/Jun/;s/7/Jul/;s/8/Aug/;s/9/Sep/;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\([0-9][0-9]*  *[A-Z][a-z][a-z] *\)[0-9][0-9]*\( .*\)/\2\1\3/'
```

Notice that `s/12/Dec/` needs to come before `s/1/Jan/`.

Comment: On one host with 200+ jobs the output seems to be sorted by id mainly--not always timestamp in the 2nd half.  Anyway, the `date` command has special timestamp-parsing powers that could make this simpler when fed the right fields eg. with `cut`.

Comment: You can pass a separate sort option on each `-k` option: `-k 3M` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks complicated but this also works:

```
atq |awk '{system("echo "$1 "  $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S \
--date \""$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6"\")  "$7"  "$8 )}' |sort -k2 
    469  2012-03-24_01-30-00  a  master
    655  2012-03-24_02-03-00  a  master
    671  2012-03-24_02-04-00  a  master
    657  2012-03-24_02-09-00  a  master
    673  2012-03-24_02-11-00  a  master
    537  2012-03-25_00-38-00  a  master
    539  2012-03-25_00-43-00  a  master
    652  2012-03-27_12-57-00  a  master
    654  2012-03-27_13-03-00  a  master
    656  2012-03-27_13-09-00  a  master
```

Compared with other suggestions I like how the actual parsing is left to `date` which understands the textual timestamp, so you can reformat to whatever you want that makes it a breeze to filter or sort later.

You can tack on a `|column -t`  at the end to nicely align and space out the fields.

Comment: Actually, a shorter version may be doable with `bash readline` instead of `awk`

Answer (score 0):

`atq` allows to define a »strftime-like time format«. One can use the epoch for easy sorting and later convert that to something readable. The epoch also has the advantage that one can make time calculations.

```bash
$ atq -o%s | sort -k2n | while read -r id epoch data; do
    echo "$id $(date --date @$epoch) $data"
done
```

I use this method in a script `atqq` that

- sorts jobs by date,
- prints out the job command, and
- shows the duration until the event is due.

Example output:

```
$ atqq
5515 2023-11-02 12:00:00 a user: "strobe blue" (1:59:08)
5514 2023-11-02 12:30:00 a user: "strobe red" (2:29:08)
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

duration() {
        local i=$1
        local d=$((i / (3600 * 24)))
        ((i %= 3600 * 24))
        local h=$((i / 3600))
        ((i %= 3600))
        local m=$((i / 60))
        local s=$((i % 60))

        if [ $d -gt 0 ]; then
                printf "%ud %u:%02u:%02u" $d $h $m $s
        elif [ $h -gt 0 ]; then
                printf "%u:%02u:%02u" $h $m $s
        elif [ $m -gt 0 ]; then
                printf "%u:%02u" $m $s
        else
                printf "%u" $s
        fi
}

now=$(date +%s)

atq -o%s | sort -k2n | while read -r id epoch data; do
        date=$(date --date @$epoch +%F\ %T)
        cmd=$(at -c $id | sed '/^$/d' | tail -1)
        diff=$((epoch - now))
        if [ $diff -gt 0 ]; then
                remaining="\e[32m$(duration $diff)\e[m"
        else
                remaining="\e[31m-$(duration ${diff#-})\e[m"
        fi

        echo -e "\e[1m$id\e[m $date $data: \e[33m\"$cmd\"\e[m ($remaining)"
done
```